# Error using Switch Case with PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to use Switch Case for show multiple components in my xhtml, but it doesnt work. As result it shows all the components. I'm using PrimeFaces 6.1 , Eclipse Mars

I'm trying to use Switch Case for show multiple components in my xhtml, but it doesnt work. As result it shows all the components. I'm using PrimeFaces 6.1 , Eclipse Mars

My Beans

```
package vista;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

public class Prueba {

    @ManagedBean  
    @ViewScoped  
    public class SwitchController {  

        private String value=null;  

        public String getValue() {  
            return value;  
        }  

        public void setValue(final String value) {  
            this.value = value;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

My XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
<h:head>
    <title>prueba</title>
</h:head>
<body>
    <h:form id="mainForm">
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />  

        <p:selectOneMenu id="caseSelection" value="#{switchController.value}">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Default case" itemValue="default" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Case 1" itemValue="case1" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="null" itemValue="#{null}" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Case 2" itemValue="case2" />  

            <p:ajax update="swichWrapper" process="@this" />  
        </p:selectOneMenu>  

        <p:separator />  

        <p:outputPanel  id="swichWrapper">  
            <pe:switch  id="switch" value="#{switchController.value}">  
                    <pe:defaultCase>  
                            Case: Default  
                    </pe:defaultCase>  

                    <pe:case value="case1">  
                            Case: <p:commandButton id="case1button" actionListener="#{switchController.listener('case1')}" update=":mainForm:growl"  
                                            value="Call listener with 'case1'" />  
                    </pe:case>  

                    <pe:case value="case2">  
                            Case: <p:commandButton id="case2button" actionListener="#{switchController.listener('case2')}" update=":mainForm:growl"  
                                            value="Call listener with 'case2'"  />  
                    </pe:case>  

                    <pe:case value="#{null}">  
                            Case: Null  
                    </pe:case>  
            </pe:switch>  
        </p:outputPanel> 
    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Result 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rPQp.png)

Comment: which version of PrimeFaces Extensions are you using?

Comment: PrimeFaces 6.1... 
I need to downloading another library for Switch Case it's work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment your problem most probably is that you are missing Primefaces extensions library. Here is what you should add to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```